# Split Address column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an address field where all the address details are held in one column, I want to create some labels so need to be able to split the address into the correct format.
Example :-

```
 ADDRESS 
PIKE ROAD, AL 36064-3401
MEMPHIS TN 38104-5802 
JAMAICA PLAIN MA 02130-2337
```

Need to split this column into

```
    City      State     Zip
  PIKE ROAD    AL       36064-3401
 MEMPHIS        TN       38104-5802
JAMAICA PLAIN   MA       02130-2337
```

I am able to extract Zip code using

```
STUFF(Address, 1, Len(Address) +1- CHARINDEX(' ',Reverse(Address)), '') from abx
```

but I am having trouble in extracting city and state. Is it possible to split the string based on the length of words, i.e. all the Characters before the length of the word (2) goes in City and all the words with 2 characters goes in state example: - Pike Road goes into the City and AL (length is 2) in the state?

Comment: Is every row `City`, two character `State` and 10 character `ZIPplus`? Do you need/want to tamp multiple whitespace characters down to a single space? If so, it seems pretty easy to replicate your existing expression to get the state. Anything before that is city. (You don't even need `CharIndex`.)

Comment: Yes format is city , two character state and 10 character zip

Comment: Just use `Len` and `SubString`. The last 10 are the ZIPplus. Skip back three more and take two characters for state. City is `Len` - 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Habo said, you only need to use `LEN` and `SUBSTRING`.

```
WITH Tbl AS(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES       
        ('PIKE ROAD, AL 36064-3401'),
        ('MEMPHIS TN 38104-5802'),
        ('JAMAICA PLAIN MA 02130-2337')
    ) t(Address)
)
SELECT
    City    = SUBSTRING(Address, 0, LEN(Address) - 13),
    State   = SUBSTRING(Address, LEN(Address) - 12, 2),
    ZipCode = SUBSTRING(Address, LEN(Address) - 9, 10)
FROM Tbl
```

Comment: You data better be very consistent!

Comment: Agreed. If he can fix the table design, it's much better to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This works for these three examples.  As @Kevin pointed out above, this works if your data is **consistent**, which is, as he said, "a very big if."

What I did was create a subquery mimicking a table.  It has one column, "x", that just has a string value.  I worked backwards to get the zip code first (which you figured out), then the state, then the street address.  The function(s) used to extract each piece of information build upon the previous one.

I haven't used SQL Server in years, so I used a [web app designed to mimick SQL Server 2014](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler).

This query **should** produce the table in the screenshot below:

[image]

```
select x
, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(x, 1, LEN(x) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(x), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(x)) + 1)), ',', '') as city
, SUBSTRING(x, LEN(x) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(x), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(x)) + 1) + 2, 2) as state
, SUBSTRING(x, LEN(x) + 2 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(x)), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(x))) as zip

FROM (
select 'PIKE ROAD, AL 36064-3401' as x 
union
select 'MEMPHIS TN 38104-5802'
union
select 'JAMAICA PLAIN MA 02130-2337'
    ) as whatever
```

HTH!

Cheers,

-Maashu

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, and it will work if your data is consistent. That is a very big IF...

```
DECLARE @ADDRESS NVARCHAR(255) = 'PIKE ROAD, AL 36064-3401'
DECLARE @DELIMITER CHAR(1) = ' '
DECLARE @POS INT
DECLARE @ZIP NVARCHAR(11)
DECLARE @STATE NVARCHAR(11)
DECLARE @CITY NVARCHAR(200)

-- get the occurrence of the last space
SET @POS = LEN(@ADDRESS) - CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,REVERSE(@ADDRESS))

--set the zip code
SET @ZIP = SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, @POS+2, 11)

--get the remaining portion of the address
SET @ADDRESS = SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, 0, @POS+1)

--set the last space again
SET @POS =  LEN(@ADDRESS) - CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,REVERSE(@ADDRESS))

--set the state and street
SET @STATE = SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, @POS+2, 11)
SET @CITY = SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, 0, @POS)

PRINT @ZIP
PRINT @STATE
PRINT @CITY
```

OUTPUT:

```
36064-3401
AL
PIKE ROAD
```

Comment: By consistent i notice the first record has a comma after city, are all zips zip+4 etc. modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is consistent and delimited, you may use the following:

```
SELECT 
  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(myAddress), ',', '.'), 1)) AS [Street],
  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(myAddress), ',', '.'), 2)) AS [City],
  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(myAddress), ',', '.'), 3)) AS [State]
FROM dbo.custAddress;
```

The above table has a column that have values of "steet, city, state" per row. Please look at [www.mssqltips.com](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6321/split-delimited-string-into-columns-in-sql-server-with-parsename/) for the entire explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

try below code to split address column:

> ```
> SELECT 
> parsename(replace(columnname,',','.'),3) as x,
> parsename(replace(columnname,',','.'),2) as y,
> parsename(replace(columnname,',','.'),1) as z
> FROM table name
> ```